# Copy one element of ordered pairs based on partial matching of the other

Tags: excel, excel-2010, lookup, vba

I wish to copy the `Areacode`s from the first table (ColumnA:B) to the second (ColumnsD:G):

[image: SO24203269 question example]

according to partially matching the addresses in ColumnD to those in ColumnA.

If the street numbers are hard to crack then the area codes based on street names only would cover maybe 95% of the cases, so sufficient.

Comment: Please anyone, it is hard hitting thousands of cells without some sort of possibility to filter information to the another table.

Comment: I am deeply sorry. I dont know how did I miss your answer and then went to a holiday and didnt notice it on second time neither. I just say, you are my hero.

Comment: Regarding to the ""After that corresponding Areacode in table one would be set to table two as well." sentence I have been unclear. But you made exactly the kind of formula that solved this problem. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try:

```
=INDEX(B:B,MATCH(LEFT(D2,LEN(D2)-2)&"*",A:A,0))
```

in E2 and copy down.